# The meaning of "not the better for it" in the following sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning

**[SOURCE](http://www.siu.edu.vn/upload/SIU%20E%20NEWS/ENGLISH/ENG%20March/Words%20words%20words.htm)**

> His assessment of Bloom—like his praise of other scholars and critics—is intensely personal, including jibes about his physical girth and style of delivery ("Bloom/Boom") **and not the better for it**.

I googled the meaning of it and got the explanation for "all the better for" is "improved as a result of". I wonder if it is correct to interpret the meaning of **and is not the better for it** in this sentence as

> (The writer) **doesn't gain anything/improve himself** (by jibing at the critic).

Comment: The phrase is well-defined in numerous dictionaries, e.g. **[Macmillan.](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-all-the-better-for-something)** The next time you encounter a word or phrase that puzzles you, why not consult a dictionary instead of "googling it" first? It will save you a step!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what "to be the better for ____" means. (Another similar wording, which I think is only possible in the negative, is "to be no better off for ____".)

However, you haven't quite got the subject right. It's the writer's *assessment* that's not better for it:

> The assessment is not improved by the inclusion of personal aspersions.

In general, when you see a possessive like "the writer's assessment", you can't take "the writer" out to be the subject of the next verb, unless you introduce a new pronoun.

So to allow your interpretation, we would need to see something like this:

> The writer's assessment of the critic includes personal aspersions ... and **he** is not the better for it.

Comment: I am confused, does "his" refer to the writer or the critic?

Comment: @TiWen It refers to the critic. The writer has made this assessment, so he is not likely to insult his own physical girth and style of delivery. :)